# gh-pages cannot build .rmd file due to UTF-8 encoding error

Tags: r, github, knitr

The following .rmd file cannot be built to gh-pages. I have been through many forums but cannot identify the problem. Knitr knits it beautifully from within RStudio but github/ jekyll has an issue.

https://github.com/steinbock/shiny/blob/master/hospitals/about.rmd

So far I have tried:

- encoding: UTF-8
- keep_md: yes
- self_contained: false

Comment: Did you try it with `self_contained: false` yet? You haven't said what you've tried so far.

Comment: Tried that too, but I still get message `The file hospitals/about.rmd is not properly UTF-8 encoded`.

Comment: The accented characters you have in there do not seem to be UTF-8 encoded. It has to do with the bytes that are in the file, not a flag you have in the header. Are you authoring the file on windows? Does your editor allow you to choose an encoding? Windows usually defaults to LATIN-1, not UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. Will post solution!

Comment: @MrFlick (via R-devel) `validUTF8(c("ä","ö","ü","â","é","è","ê","ô"))` == `[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`

Comment: But @hrbrmstr it depends on how you created those character. Copy/pasting isn't reliable because translations can happen in the browser or OS. They are valid character that can be in UTF-8, but it depends on how they are encoded in the file. Somehow you created UTF-8 versions. Are you on Windows? I guess it doesn't matter because the OP solved this by changing the encoding which was the point.

Comment: worked on linux (ubuntu) and Mac OS X. I try not to ever have to deal with Windows :-). Point is well-taken though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the .rmd file was being saved with the default encoding on the windows machine: ISO-8859-1.

To solve this in RStudio I clicked:

File -> Save with Encoding... -> Selected UTF-8 and set as default encoding for source files.

Now it works.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if it solved your problem.